# GSheet Script requirement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to be able to achieve this on my google sheet.

Requirements.

1. IF Column B is not equal to the word " Pending ". Delete that row
2. IF the row gets updated and the content on Column B for that row gets updated AND IS NOT EQUAL to the wor " Pending". Delete that row as well.

So I would like to achieve auto row delete for existing and future updates on the sheet.

Thank you!

Comment: What will initiate this process of deleting rows that have Pending in column B?

Comment: Are you asking others to write code for you? What is your programming question?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the name of the sheet in the getSheetByName method to whatever you want. Deleting rows goes a lot easier if you start from the bottom. This function will do the deleting.  The remaining issue is what's going to initiate the process.  Perhaps a timed trigger?

```
function delIfBPending()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('delIfPending');//Change this name as needed
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  for(var i=rngA.length-1;i>-1;i--)//this limit is dependent upon whether or not you have a header row.
  {
    if(rngA[i][1]=='Pending')
    {
      sht.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```